# Action cable + Sidekiq + Roo - Displaying csv rows count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, actioncable, roo

I have a model called Scanner the purpose of this is upload a xlsx file through active storage and  then process the file in the background with sidekiq and roo gem to create a new txt file. That process it's working perfectly. The part where I am stuck is that during the process of xlsx file is reading I want to display in the show view the count of analized rows till the txt file its completed generated, that's why I am implementing action cable however is not still working. Here the code:

[Show View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo6ki.png)

Please any help, thanks in advance.

**/app/models/scanner.rb**

```
class Scanner < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :target_file
  has_many_attached :documents

  after_create_commit do 
    ScannerBroadcastJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

**/app/jobs/scanner_broadcast_job.rb**

```
class ScannerBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
 queue_as :default

  def perform(scanner)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('scanners_channel', {
      analized_rows: render_analized_rows(scanner)
    })
  end

  private
    def render_analized_rows(scanner)
      ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'scanners/scanner', 
      locals: { scanner: scanner })  
    end
 end
```

**/app/channels/scanner_channel.rb**

```
 class ScannerChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
   def subscribed
    stream_from "scanners_channel"
   end

   def unsubscribed
   end

   def create(data)
     Scanner.create({ analized_rows: data['analized_rows'] })
   end
end
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/channels/scanner.coffee**

```
App.scanner = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ScannerChannel",
  connected: ->
  disconnected: ->
  received: (data) ->
    $("#analized_rows").append(data["analized_rows"])  
  create: (analized_rows) ->
    @perform 'create', analized_rows: analized_rows
```

**/app/views/scanners/_scanner.html.erb**

```
<div class="scanner" id='analized_rows'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Filename</th>
          <td class="text-center"><%= scanner.filename %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Status</th>
          <td class="text-center"><%= scanner.status %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Analized Rows</th>
          <td class="text-center"><%= scanner.analized_rows %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Target File</th>
          <td class="text-center"><%= link_to 
            scanner.target_file.blob.filename, url_for(scanner.target_file) 
            %> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what isn't working ?

Comment: @GorillaApe whereas the xlsx file is getting read in the show view the analyzed rows isn’t showing the progress without reload the page. The attached image in the post is when I reload the page after 5 seconds